# Simluate a file upload POST request via Postman

Tags: post, file-upload, http-headers, postman

I'm developing a file upload method and I wanna test it independently of a frontend interface.

Normally I would use an HTML `form` to send a file using the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` headers.

Now as I get it, the files are converted to `base64` and sent as strings.
I'm using [this tool](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file) to convert a file to `base64`, but with both `multipart` or `form-data` headers Postman gives me this error:

> 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to encode the file yourself, you need to use form-data, change key type from text to file and select the file as below:
[image: postman screenshot]